# c# windows form ( adding information to access data base )

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

i am trying to add information to the database but a always get an error this is my codes right now

```
 public partial class User : Form
{

    public OleDbConnection conect = new OleDbConnection();
    public User()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mhamad\Desktop\form\Item.mdb;
                                        Persist Security Info=False;";
    }


    private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conect;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Item ";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                combo.Items.Add(reader["Item_Name"].ToString());

            }
            conect.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void combo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            conect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conect;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Item where Item_Name='"+combo.Text+"'";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                item_id.Text = reader["Item_ID"].ToString();

                Price.Text = reader["Item_Price"].ToString();
            }
            conect.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void Buy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conect;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Admin_Items ([Item_Name],[Price]) value('" + combo.Text + "','" + Price.Text + "')";

            MessageBox.Show("Success");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" +ex);
        }
```

so this is my code right now when i try to add the information to the data base always give me this error [Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5bdE.png)
and this is my data base [database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHT8l.png)
i used that code to insert the data for my sign up form and it worked with out problems
i want to add the items that shown in the combo box and the price to the data base after that i want to link that data base to the admin form to be shown 
but i'm stuck here now
this is error code 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find output table 'Admin_Items'.'
from the code 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: It should be VALUE**S**, not `... VALUE (...` in your insert query.

Comment: ... and I would strongly recommend to use parameters instead of concatenating values for your SQL statements. [Exploits Of A Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @Filburt i changed that too now still didn't work :( 
thanks

Comment: You'll have to give us a little more than *"doesn't work"*. Debug and inspect the insert statement - if you still get a SQL syntax error we need to see what get's sent to your database.

Comment: @Filburt will im beginner and this is my collage project 
i dont know what to give more actually i gave the error and the codes also the database all are connected and work the other forms work with out problems but i dont know why i get this error

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on the line `MessageBox.Show("Success");` and inspect the value of `command.CommandText`.

Comment: @Filburt the error is in command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Your database name in your "database pic" is "item.accdb" but in your code is "Item.mdb"

Comment: @bradbury9 i dont know how to thank you :)  i didnt even noticed that 
thanks again for helping :) its working know

Answer (score 1):

you should edit the insert query

```
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
   cmd.CommandText = "insert into Admin_Items (Item_Name ,Price) values (@item, @price)";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", combo.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price.Text);
```

hope will works

take a look to [this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: it didn't work :( but thanks :)

Comment: edited @MhamadAras

Comment: i changed the cmd to command but it didnt work it says the error is on
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: edited, try again

Comment: still doesn't work :( sorry for taking your time

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @MhamadAras Telling us "it doesn't work" isn't useful.  Give us the error messages.  Update your question with an updated code.

Comment: @LarsTech i edited the picture the error code and added the error code at the end

Comment: You should double check the database name, check my comment in your question